# getting the attributes of xml that is not in a separate file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Trying unsuccessfully to get the attributes of the XML below with the javascript code shown underneath, not sure it won't work, any help?:

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!- some fancy stuff here

 -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<details ><detail id="101" name="Vincent" address="KilWith" 
busname="vintechsurveys" lat="-1.28" lng="36.79" distance="3.796344552327"/>
<detail id="102" name="Dan" address="Derman" 
busname="fancyname" lat="-1.29" lng="39.79" distance="11.796344552327"/> 
</details>

<script>
var detailNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("detail");
for (var i = 0; i < detailNodes.length; i++)
       {
         var id = detailNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
         var name = detailNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         .....
       }
</script>
</body>
```

PS, note that the XML is not in a different file

Comment: *not sure why it wont work

Comment: XML documents are allowed only one root element. `<script>` is an **HTML** tag and has no meaning in an arbitrary chunk of XML.

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong formatting, the script is not part of the XML

Comment: If it isn't part of the XML and the XML isn't a separate file … then what **do** you have?

Comment: The script and the xml are all in the same file, because it (the xml part) was generated dynamically with php, and echoed to the document

Comment: So it **is** part of the XML then?

Comment: first things first the file is not .xml, it is a php file. I have truncated some parts

Comment: File extensions don't matter on the WWW. It's the HTTP headers that matter for determining what type of data a URL returns. Do you mean that you have a PHP program which outputs a `Content-Type: text/html` header (because that is what PHP does (unless you override it) when you run it from a webserver, followed by a chuck of XML (which isn't HTML, so the content-type header is just wrong), followed by an HTML script element? Because that's just wrong, don't do that.

Comment: I've edited the question, kindly have a look

Comment: OK, that's just an invalid HTML document. Don't do that.

Comment: Oops didnt know, Does that mean it Wont work